# How to identify individual single click and double click view in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

In my application, want to identify single click and double click on View. 
My actual problem is when double click on view that time single click also occurred. And single click is working perfectly..So
How to identify individual single click and double click on view ?

My code is :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self fullscreenGallery];
   [self video_image_Gallery];
}
-(void)video_image_Gallery
{
   UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
   doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
   doubleTap.delegate = self;
   [image_scroll addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
}
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
{
   [self performSelector:@selector(fullscreenGallery) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
   UIScrollView * imageScroll = (UIScrollView *)gestureRecognizer.view;
   self.header_view.hidden=NO;
   float newScale = [imageScroll zoomScale] + ZOOM_STEP;
   if (newScale > imageScroll.maximumZoomScale)
   {
      newScale = imageScroll.minimumZoomScale;
      CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];
      [imageScroll zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
   }
   else
   {
      self.header_view.hidden=YES;
      newScale = imageScroll.maximumZoomScale;
      CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];
      [imageScroll zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
   }
}
```

Comment: I think is not possible in gesture , if you want to know that use touch end method

Comment: Are you adding these to the exact same view ? In your code you are adding to 2 different views  ( image_scroll and self.view ) ...

Comment: i added 2 differentt view imagescroll and sub view in mainview

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with single click vs double click ? Would using a long press gesture for double click be easier ? That way you can keep single click.

Comment: in my application have gallery view.. when single click occur   that time header and footer will hide like our phone gallery.. and when double click that time image zoom in - out .. so i want solution for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below code in your application

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:    self action:@selector(handleSingleTap)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTap.delaysTouchesEnded = YES;

UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:   self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap)];
doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;


[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];


-(void)handleSingleTap
{
  NSLog(@"The single tap happened");
}

-(void)handleDoubleTap
{
  NSLog(@"The double tap happened");
}
```

Above code works perfectly.I tried above coding.it works individually.Check it.

Comment: I have tried this one also  .. but when  double  click that time same issue occur

Comment: Welcome MY FRIEND Stela:)

Answer (score 0):

Add the same target for both gestures,

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
doubleTap.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTap.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

delay the first tap handler

```
- (void) handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    [self performSelector:@selector(handleSingleTap:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
    if(sender.numberOfTapsRequired == 2) {
        NSLog(@"Double tap:");
      [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    }
}

- (void) handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    NSLog(@"Single tap:");
}
```

Comment: no i cant chnage [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

Comment: You can change your view there buddy, it's an example.

Comment: I have tested it before I posted here.. If your are tapping slowly then try to increase target delay... In this code it is 0.5 seconds.

Comment: no still not working properly .. please give me  another solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89124/discussion-between-stela-and-rohit-kumar).

Comment: Couldn't find where you have added your single tap gesture.